# categories are showing up the full <a href> tag instead of just %s with a hyperlink

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've got a bit of a problem, I'm a newbie to php but I needed to figure out a fix for this on my website. It sets it to being the full string in the apostrophes instead of making the  css properly work. I've added images as examples to the actual result and the expected result. I can change whatever is in the apostrophes and it works but the css is not actually applied.

I found out when editing the source code in inspect element that the code instead of having the < and > tags it has &lt ; instead of < and &gt ; instead of > (no spaces between the semi colons)

I have identified this to be the part of code which sets the category title.

---

```
// Wrap category title into link
if ( !function_exists( 'insugroup_woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title' ) ) {
    //Handler of the add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'insugroup_woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title' );
    function insugroup_woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title($cat) {
        if (insugroup_storage_get('in_product_item') && is_object($cat)) {
            $cat->name = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url(get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat')), $cat->name);
        }
        return $cat;
    }
}
```

[image: Example of Actual Result]

[image: Example of Expected Result]

Comment: relevant? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301871/encode-text-string-being-appended-as-query-to-url

Comment: code you posted have nothing to do with converting html special chars to html entities, make sure you don't have `esc_html_e` in template

Comment: It seems to be $cat->name is html escape and it will not work with any html tag. Only pure text will be display. You will need to identify from the template file of your theme, if you can add link to title.

Comment: can OP wrap the contents of $cat-name in `html_entity_decode()`?

Comment: @Mech Adding urlencode or urlencode_deep doesn't effect the outcome. I might be doing it wrong but it didn't break the website so I just think it had no result meaning it could be doing it already elsewhere.

Comment: @Kazz I've tried finding `esc_html_e` but it is not used, at least not in this php file. `esc_html` on the otherhand is used frequently, is this related?

Comment: @Mech wrapping contents in `html_entity_decode()` removed all the categories except the first one, leaving it with no name at all - completely empty.

Comment: @HWSiew could you elaborate? How would I go about doing this, like I mentioned I'm not familiar with PHP too much and this is really the only thing I need in the whole website that's PHP based. Thanks.

Comment: @Aethiral, did you wrap the `'<a href="%s">%s</a>'` part, the `$cat->name`, or `sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url(get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat')), $cat->name)`?

Comment: @Mech if you mean wrapped it all as one within it then yeah, but I didn't wrap them separately.

Comment: Might be worth giving it a go.